# how to stop conntrack sessions

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have router with linux system based. I have the related SDK to customize the linux system of the router.

When I disable a port forwarding from iptables rules, the running conntrack sessions do not go down and keep established.

I want to stop all running conntrack sessions when I disable a port forwarding from iptable rules. I mean, only remove the conntrack sessions related to the removed rule. So stop all conntrack sessions with dest IP (lan IP) = the dest IP of removed rule.

How to do that in kernel space? how to develop a kernel module that go over all conntrack session and check the destination IP and remove only the session with a given ipaddress? are there some link for that?

Are there a user space way ( C functions or Linux commands) to stop specific conntrack sessions ?

Comment: Do you mean conntrack?  If so, why not remove the conntrack modules ?

Comment: @davidgo howto to remove conntrack modules

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `conntrack` tool has options to remove individual states or to flush the entire state table. It uses Netlink to interface with the kernel.

```
conntrack --delete --orig-port-dst 80
```

Comment: thx for the answer, how to delete by ip address and not by port ?

Comment: Does this will stop immediately the running conntrack ?